# Using jQuery to do a slide transition when hiding one div and displaying another overtop of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to create a slide up effect using jQuery or pure css.

I have a container div and then 2 content divs inside. I would like to achieve an effect like in the first tile in [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tilelist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) on mouse hover and mouse out.

Please see this https://jsfiddle.net/jfyacwvg/ of my current code. You will notice that when hovering over Item 1 the paragraph appears. This is fine but I want it to appear with some sort of slide effect.

Please do not mind the fact that Item 2 and 3 change when hovering Item 1, I will have to fix that later on.

Here is my JavaScript code to hide show, but please see the jsfiddle link for everything:

```
$(".card").hover(
  function () {
      $(".content-1").hide();
      $(".content-2").show();
  }, function() {
      $(".content-2").hide();
      $(".content-1").show();
    }
);
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="content-1" style="height: 300px">
                     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" />
                     <h3 class="text-center">Item 1</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-2" style="display: none; height: 300px;">
                        <p style="margin:30px 0 30px 0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="content-1" style="height: 300px">
                     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" />
                     <h3 class="text-center">Item 2</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-2" style="display: none; height: 300px;">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="card">
                    <div class="content-1" style="height: 300px">
                     <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="img-responsive" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" />
                     <h3 class="text-center">Item 3</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content-2" style="display: none; height: 300px;">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to supply your minimal, relevant code here so it will be viewable by others in the future when you remove that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this JSFiddle, it is done in CSS.

https://jsfiddle.net/de8L2f1L/

The position of the `p` inside the `div` is at the `top: 0px;` just as it normally would be. When you hover over the `p` it then moves up, `top: -200px` with a transition of 2 seconds (which can be changed). The reason it is set to change to -200px is because the height of your `div` is 200px.

`overflow: hidden` was applied to the div to keep it from expanding with the size of the `p`.

One thing you need to worry about is that your `img`, `p`, etc do not span more than twice height of the div because you would then always be missing the content in the middle as it would go from being hidden below to being hidden above.

Comment: jquery already has the effect method (slideUp/slideDown). There is no need to do it with CSS ;)

Comment: Why the need to do it in JQuery? It is a matter of preference I suppose. But hey, now he has a solution for either.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using. The slideUp slideDown jQuery version was definitely an excellent answer, but just wasn't as smooth.

Answer (score 3):

It's just change the hide/show for slideUp/slideDown:

```
        $(".card").hover(
      function () {
          $(".content-1").slideUp();
          $(".content-2").slideDown();
      }, function() {
          $(".content-2").slideUp();
          $(".content-1").slideDown();
        }
    );
```

Your fiddle updated:

https://jsfiddle.net/jfyacwvg/2/